# python update tk.optionmenu drop down selections

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter, optionmenu

I have a superclass (tk window) , and another subclass (tk window) which inherits properties from the original class. on the super class, I have a method `callback` which is called every second. The subclass displays a tk options menu, and i would like to update the options displayed in the tk options menu though the superclass method which is called every second. I've created a shortened version of my program which shows generally what I'm trying to do. This program will run, and it works as i'd like it to, but in pycharm I receive a warning highlighting the subclass method `def update(self, controller):`:

```
Signature of method 'OtherPage.update()' does not match 
   signature of base method in class 'Misc'
```

what is the correct way to do this?

```
import tkinter as tk

exchanges = ['Bitfinex', 'Bittrex', 'Kraken', 'Gdax']

class Trader(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Multi-Trader-Wallet")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)

        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=lambda: print('exit'))
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)
        self.exchange1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.frames = {}
        self.id = self.after(1000, self.callback)

        for F in (MainPage, OtherPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(OtherPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]

        frame.tkraise()

    def callback(self):

        print('callback')
        print(self.frames[OtherPage])
        self.frames[OtherPage].update(self)
        self.id = self.after(1000, self.callback)


class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text='MainPage')
        label.grid(row=1, column=1)


class OtherPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text='OtherPage')
        label2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        drop = tk.OptionMenu(self, controller.exchange1, *exchanges)
        drop.config(width=10)
        drop.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def update(self, controller):
        exchanges.append('new exchange')
        drop = tk.OptionMenu(self, controller.exchange1, *exchanges)
        drop.config(width=10)
        drop.grid(row=2, column=1)

app = Trader()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: every tkinter's widget has built-in method `update()` to redraw so you overwrite it and maybe it makes problem - try to use different name. But you have to show full Traceback to say something more.

Comment: It is only warning in PyCharm - do you have any problem to run code ?

Comment: I don't see your `update` calling parent class `update`, so you are completely overriding the original tkinter widgets `update` method, and I think you are also doing a different thing. Why don't you call it something else? You may break something with this (your widget won't update besides what you change in it by hand in your custom update)